# Sql Loader not finishing through HTTP request

Tags: php, oracle, http, sql-loader

I am trying to import data through SQL Loader into an oracle database through a file upload on a PHP website.  When I run the import through the browser, the last commit is missing:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ESTEO\data>sqlldr  'db/pw' 
>   control=sqlLoaderFiles/file.ctl   log='LoadResults.log'
>
> SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Mon Feb 11 16:51:26
>   2019
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights
>   reserved.
>
> Commit point reached - logical record count 26 Commit point reached -
>   logical record count 52 Commit point reached - logical record count 78
>   Commit point reached - logical record count 104

When I run the import through the command line I get:

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ESTEO\data>sqlldr  'db/pw' 
>   control=sqlLoaderFiles/file.ctl   log='LoadResults.log'
>
> SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Mon Feb 11 16:51:26
>   2019
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights
>   reserved.
>
> Commit point reached - logical record count 26 Commit point reached -
>   logical record count 52 Commit point reached - logical record count 78
>   Commit point reached - logical record count 104 Commit point reached -
>   logical record count 113

My control file is here:

```
    OPTIONS (

    skip=1,

    errors=100000,

    parallel=true

)

----------------------------------------------------------------------

LOAD DATA

   INFILE        'files/data.csv'

   BADFILE       'c:\temp\data_BAD.log'

   DISCARDFILE   'c:\temp\data_DISCARDED.log'

   TRUNCATE

   INTO TABLE     table

----------------------------------------------------------------------

Fields Terminated    by ","

Optionally Enclosed  by '"'

Trailing Nullcols

----------------------------------------------------------------------

   (columns)
```

The command I am using is here:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ESTEO\data\sqlLoaderFiles\run_sqlloader.bat db pw sqlLoaderFiles/file.ctl
```

The batch file is here:

```
sqlldr  '%1/%2@server'  control=%3   log='LoadResults.log'
```

I checked LoadResults.log and it showed 113 records being loaded even though only 104 actually were.

Why is the last commit not finishing through the HTTP request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.  The last record had bad data I didn't need anyway.  Removing it solved the issue.